# Stop bookmarklets showing up in address bar (omnibox) when searching for Javascript results

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

If I use the keyword `Javascript` in the address bar in chrome (starting in Chrome 37) all of my bookmarklets show up in the autocomplete address bar until I get past the word javascript

E.g. typing  `javascript sort` brings up all my bookmarklets in the autocomplete portion of the address bar).

It's not a huge deal but it is a bit of a pain.  Is there any way I can stop this other than removing the bookmarklets?

Comment: Do you wish to (1) remove them from browsing history, which is fairly easy to do in `chrome://history/`, or (2) be able to turn on and off their display without removing them from history?

Comment: @harrymc He means bookmarks, not history.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91378

There is an extension called Fauxbar, but you might not want it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably the same as this known issue :
[Issue 416148: Omnibox Displays Javascript Bookmarklet Suggestions](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=416148).

> Steps to reproduce the problem:
>  
>   1. Create a bookmarklet
>   2. Type "javascript" into the omnibox
>   3. See that the omnibox is filled out with the entire bookmarklet script
>
> What is the expected behavior?   
> Do not include bookmarklets (anything
>   that starts with the javascript: protocol) since a user would not
>   manually type that out as an option
>
> What went wrong?   
> Typing "ja" shows expected results based on
>   previous searches and visited pages. Typing an additional "v" fills up
>   the entire omnibox with a bookmarklet script, making it difficult to
>   see what has already been typed.

This is marked as fixed and verified on November 3, 2014, on
Windows 7,40.0.2209.0 (Official Build) canary.
The fix itself is mentioned [here](https://codereview.chromium.org/695693002) as committed.

So it seems like you only need to wait for the next update of Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Chrome extension called [Secure Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-bookmarks/leocjgngiajhfiikjolfhcpiokgbinep?hl=en) which stores your bookmarks separately and requires a password to access them. You can store all your bookmarklets in this extension as these bookmarks will not appear in your Chrome's omnibox while searching.