# Show bookmarklets in Firefox location bar results?

Tags: firefox, address-bar, bookmarklet

I'm a heavy bookmarklet user and even heavier user of Firefox keywords. Combined, they're a real powerful tool in dealing with different situations on the web.

Sometimes it's hard to remember all those keywords you assigned to bookmarked bookmarklets, so it would be good if Firefox showed bookmarklets if their names or addresses were typed in location bar (that is [the "Awesome Bar"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-search-firefox-bookmarks-history-tabs)). What I want is the exact opposite of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/808440/is-there-any-way-to-stop-bookmarklets-showng-up-in-the-address-bar-when-searchin). However, it shows only "normal" bookmarks which addresses begin with `http`, not `javascript:`.

I searched in Google and Bugzilla and here's [the relevant bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=913751). But still there's hope that it's possible to find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the relevant bug report, [the last comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=913751#c10) actually had mentioned the solution as follows.

> Brent Goodrick (Reporter)
>   Comment 10 • 4 years ago (2015-11-18 08:20 PST)
>
> Setting browser.urlbar.filter.javascript to false works for me too
>   (Firefox version 42.0). I would consider this bug fixed then. Thanks
>   Marco!

The last comment was made about one year from the asked date on Super User.

The entry 'browser.urlbar.filter.javascript' can still be found in `about:config` to this answered date; just toggle the value from 'true' to 'false'. Tested working in Firefox 67.0.